# Javascript file not loading on port 8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm just starting backend development so bear with me. I have here a javascript program that gets text data from my localhost. I built an HTTP server with node. Just a regular HTTP server and set it to my root folder which contains both my HTML file and a text document.

```
http-server "C:\users\mycomputer\Desktop\JSTEST"
```

in the command prompt. (I'm using windows 10)

when I go to port 8080, it says 404 not found and is not showing my app, let alone getting the information the client requested.

I originally tried to set up an express,js server because I thought it would be easier but it didn't work either. I also tried setting different paths to the HTTP server in the command prompt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>

window.onunload = function() { debugger; }

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The results would be good if the page appeared and after pressing the button in the program, the text changes to HELLO (which is written inside the txt file).

Comment: I want to add This is the error shown: This page isn’t working localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT       and its on google chrome

Comment: What is the output of `http-server "C:\users\mycomputer\Desktop\JSTEST"`? And what is the content of the `JSTEST` folder

Comment: that command is written in the command prompt to start an http-server at that project folder. the contents : jstest (html file), and xmlhttp_info.txt (standard txt file), bot in the same folder. Sorry and the OUTPUT is: Starting up http-server, serving that file path you wrote available on: http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: and opening `http://127.0.0.1:8080` gives you 404? and opening `http://127.0.0.1:8080/xmlhttp_info.txt`?

Comment: This is the error I get when I run the above: This page isn’t working localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [`Github Issue`](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/525 this is a known `http-server` issue which affects the versions 0.10.x and above.

So, uninstall the current `http-server` by,

```
npm uninstall http-server -g
```

And then reinstall the 0.9.0 version,

```
npm install -g http-server@0.9.0
```

But if you want to use `express` to serve the folder you can use the [`static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) method.

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express(); // better instead
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(8080, ()=>{console.log('Server Started')});
```

Given this `.js` file inside the `JSTEST` folder and you are running it by `node <filename>.js`

**Note:** It will not show the directory listings when you open `127.0.0.1:8080`. However, it will serve the `xmlhttp_info.txt` file if you open `127.0.0.1:8080/xmlhttp_info.txt`

Comment: And there is no way to get the data when I click on the button in the actual html document?

Comment: yeah yeah, you're doing ajax req to the `127.0.0.1:8080/xmlhttp_info.txt` you will get the file contents.

Comment: Oh man... I finally got it to work. It was confusing I had to type in "xmlhttp_info.txt.txt" instead of the above.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a get endpoint with express.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const PORT = 8080;

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"folderName","index.html")); //folderName is optional
//res.send("Hello World")//sends just text
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("listening");
});
```

instead of hardcoding the path of the file that you wanna display, path.join()is used. different os systems have different filesysystem so u wont get error when u use your app on different os. path is built-in module, u dont need to install.

second part of your question. let's say you are displaying index.html. inside the file

```
<body>

<h2 id="content">Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<div id="demo">
<button type="button" id="change">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
const $content=document.getElementById("content");
const $button=document.getElementById("change");
$button.addEventListener("click",()=>{
$content.innerHTML="hello World"
//$content.textContent="hello World" 
})
</script>
```

Comment: thanx but I actually want to get the text from the file on my computer. xmlhttp_info.txt. How can I do that? also is there a way to use vanilla js to do this? Im trying to get the basics down first. Thanks alot in advance.